# How to concatenate 2 numpy arrays of shape (A,B,C,D) and (A,E)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array A of shape (2000, 30, 64, 64, 1). Another numpy array B has a shape (2000, 30, 4). I need to concatenate both of these arrays, constructing another numpy array of shape (2000, 30, 64, 64, 1, 4).

I have tried the basic concatenation commands like:

- np.stack
- np.concatenate
- np.vstack
- np.column_stack

However, all of them lead to the same exception being thrown:

```
A.shape # (2000, 30, 64, 64, 1)
B.shape # (2000, 30, 4)

----> 1 np.concatenate([A, B])

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

None of the stack overflow solutions seem to work for this. Thoughts?

Comment: Let's count dimensions.  `A` has 5.  `B` has 3.  The result is supposed to have 6.  You need to add dimensions to both `A` and `B`.  Also the arrays have to the same shape on all dimensions except the one you are joining them on.  Which dimension are you intending to join them on?  Maybe you should practice concatenating some smaller cases first, like the examples in the function documentation.

Comment: One array has 245760000 elements, the other 240000, and you propose to create an array that is 4x the size of A, 983040000.  That doesn't make sense, does it?  Are you going to replicate `A` 4 times?  How many times are you replicating `B`?